# CryptoJs is not decrypting URL on my NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I am forwarding API calls from my frontend to my backend. I encrypt the API calls using CryptoJS.AES using the passphrase 'somekey'.

My relevant client code is...

```
var host = 'http://localhost:3000'

$('.send-button').click(function(){
  var request = $('.request-input').val();
  var encryptedRequest = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(request, 'somekey');
  console.log(encryptedRequest.toString())  
  var decryptedRequest = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedRequest, 'somekey');
  console.log('Decrypted Request: ' + decryptedRequest.toString());
  handleRequest(encryptedRequest.toString());
});

var handleRequest = function(request){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: host + '/requests?call=' + request,
        success: function(data) {
        var rawJSON = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        editor.setValue(rawJSON);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
   });
}
```

relevant server side code is...

```
var port = 3000;
var serverUrl = "127.0.0.1";

var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var CryptoJs = require("crypto-js");
var app = express(); 

app.get('/requests', function(req, res) {
    console.log('REQUEST: ' + req);
    var call = req.query.call;
    console.log(call)
    console.log("To send: " + CryptoJs.AES.decrypt(call, 'somekey'));
});
```

The problem I keep getting is that it that when I decrypt it it either doesn't get the original URL and instead returns a bunch of jibberish. An example of this is...

```
Encryption: U2FsdGVkX1/NRbZkyP60pPu3Cb9IcQ4b9n4zJkExp2LNR3O1EdEpqHLNACnYuatN

Decryption: 68747470733a2f2f6e6577736170692e6f72672f76312f61727469636c6573
```

OR... It just returns nothing and appears blank.

Ideally I would like something like this.

```
Encryption: U2FsdGVkX1/NRbZkyP60pPu3Cb9IcQ4b9n4zJkExp2LNR3O1EdEpqHLNACnYuatN

Decryption: https://newsapi.org/v1/articles
```

Can anyone see what I am dong wrong?

Comment: Update: Corrected a slight mistake. But still have the same issue. Code has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5Lr6z4zp/1/

The encryption results in a Base64 string, while the decrypted string is Hex. To get back the “Message” you need to convert that to Utf8: decryptedRequest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

Here is the relevant part of the code that works:

```
var request = "testing decryption";
var encryptedRequest = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(request, 'somekey');
console.log(encryptedRequest)  
var decryptedRequest = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedRequest, 'somekey');
var decryptedMessage = decryptedRequest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
console.log('Decrypted Request: ' + decryptedMessage);
```

Here is a link for a resources that explains the encryption/decryption in more detail:
http://www.davidebarranca.com/2012/10/crypto-js-tutorial-cryptography-for-dummies/

Comment: Thank you! It worked. However I now seem to be getting performance issues. Sometimes it takes ages to decrypt the message and, often, if just returns blank lines. Occasionally it will even through an exception Error: Malformed UTF-8 data.

Comment: Recieved:
Recieved: https://newsapi.org/v1/articles
Recieved:
Recieved:
Recieved:
Recieved:
Recieved: 

This is an example of my  node logs.

Comment: Maybe you should send the encrypted request as is to the backend in the handler rather than converting it to string and then sending it.